# Mod_rewrite issue in setting up on Snow Leopard

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, osx-snow-leopard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

I have come back to this as got sidelined on other things for ages. So please find my  details below, with these details i get the following error still:

```
   500 Internal Server Error

   The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

   Please contact the server administrator, you@example.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

   More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

my url:

```
  localhost/exp/index.php
```

My htaccess:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule (.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$
  exp/index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

Now if I comment out all except the 'RewriteEngine On'

```
  RewriteEngine On
  #RewriteRule (.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$
  #exp/index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

my /etc/apache2/httpd.conf file details are below:

```
 <Directory />
     Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
     AllowOverride All
     Order allow,deny
     Allow from all
 </Directory>


 <Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/">
   Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymlinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

Mac Snow Leopard.
My directory is within DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents" and I do not use the normal http://localhost/~User/ but http://localhost/?? etc

This might or might not but just noticed that if I list my directories by just going to localhost then the folder I am using is not visible??? within the list of other folders

So to the life of me do not know whats going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)$ /exp/index.php?page=$1&action=$2&id=$3
```

Comment: thanks for this, must have been something to do with the white space then??? i also REMOVED the /exp/ and that worked cheers